# Add a flag depending whether a value in a row exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table (tbl_liabilities) with 5 columns like this:

```
+------------+------------+-------+------------+------------+   
| User_id    | Name       | Type  |  Amount    | Delinquency|
+------------+------------+-------+------------+------------+
```

Now imagine records like this.

```
1| Luigi | Housing  | 100 | 1 Month
1| Luigi | Housing  | 200 | Null
1| Luigi | Housing  | 150 | 1 Month
1| Luigi | Mortage  | 60  | NULL
1| Luigi | Mortage  | 30  | NULL
1| Luigi | Revolving| 60  | 2 Months
1| Luigi | Other    | 100 | NULL
1| Luigi | Housing  | 100 | NULL
2| Toad  | Housing  | 200 | NULL
2| Toad  | Revolving| 150 | 1 Months
2| Toad  | Revolving| 60  | NULL
2| Toad  | Revolving| 30  | NULL
2| Toad  | Other    | 60  | NULL
2| Toad  | Other    | 100 | NULL
```

I looking for a query that returns the sum and the count of each type of liabilities (Housing, Mortage, Revolving, Other) for each client, and whether they had a delinquency in that specific liability or not.

The output should be something like this.

```
+------------+------------+...|---------------+-----------------------------+  
| User_id    | Name       |...|(Liability)Sum |  (Liability)DelinquencyFlag |
+------------+------------+...+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

For example for the aforementioned table, the result would be.

`id`, `name`, `h_sum`, `H_flag`, `M_sum`, `M_flag`, `R_sum`, `R_flag`, `O_sum`, `O_flag`,

```
id|  name |h_sum|H_flag|M_sum|M_flag|R_sum|R_flag|O_sum|O_flag 
1 | Luigi | 550 | YES  |  90 |  NO  |  60 |  YES | 100 |  NO 
2 | Toad  | 100 | NO   |  0  |  NO  | 240 |  YES | 160 |  NO
```

What I do for gathering the Liability sum is the following, for each type.

```
isnull(SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'H' THEN Amount END), 0) AS H_SUM
```

but I'm having trouble implementing the delinquency flag.
Any clue is welcome, thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Instead of `SUM()`, try `MAX()`:

```
select id, name,
       sum(case when type = 'Housing' then amount else 0 end) as h_amount,
       max(case when type = 'Housing' and Delinquency is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as h_delinquency
from liabilities l
group by id, name
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I have a follow up question if you have time.  What if the Delinquency Column has noisy rows, like instead of 1 month, could have 1 house, 3 cars, so I need to check out first if it has the word month.   Something like the following query would work? ->       max(case when type = 'Housing' and Delinquency is not null  AND Delinquency like '%month% 'then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as h_delinquency

Comment: @MarioVega . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample "noisy" data and a clear explanation of what you want.